# pandas list of json into columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a json column. the json column contains an array of json objects. how can I normalize this json data into columns and keep the main id for the record

CSV data:

```
id  actions
1   [{"A": 47, "action": "views"}]
2   [{"K": 70, "action": "conversions"}, {"J": 83, "action": "views"}]
```

expected data frame output should be something like this:

```
#   A    K    J     action        id
# 0 47   0    0     views         1
# 1 0    70   0     conversions   2
# 2 0    0    83    views         2
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `ast` convert string to object

```
df=pd.read_csv('WI.csv')
df
Out[1307]:
   id                                            actions
0   1                     [{"A": 47, "action": "views"}]
1   2  [{"K": 70, "action": "conversions"}, {"J": 83,...


import ast
df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval)
pd.DataFrame(df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval).sum()).fillna(0)
Out[1319]: 
      A     J     K       action
0  47.0   0.0   0.0        views
1   0.0   0.0  70.0  conversions
2   0.0  83.0   0.0        views
```

Update

```
pd.DataFrame(df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval).sum(),index=df.id.repeat(df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval).str.len())).fillna(0)
Out[151]: 
       A     J     K       action
id                               
1   47.0   0.0   0.0        views
2    0.0   0.0  70.0  conversions
2    0.0  83.0   0.0        views
```

Comment: @iambdot `pd.DataFrame(df.actions.apply(ast.literal_eval).sum(),index=df.id.repeat(df.actions.str.len())).fillna(0)`

Comment: I am getting cast error `TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('int64') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'`